# Stackdriver Logging API authentication issue via API Key mechanism

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to fetch stackdriver log entries using this REST API: `https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:list?key={MY_API_KEY}`

I have created an API Key as per the steps mentioned here and set API restrictions to Stackdriver API, Stackdriver Logging API and Stackdriver Monitoring API.

#### Request Body

```
"resourceNames": [
    "projects/{MY_PROJECT}"
  ]
}
```

#### Response

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? What do I need to modify to make this work?
The same API call works via the OAuth2.0 authentication mechanism, but not with the API Key mechanism.

**Note**: My use-case requires me to use the REST APIs, and I cannot use the Service Account + SDK flow.

Answer (score 4):

This method of authentication is not currently possible as per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys). Logging and Monitoring API do not support API key authentication at this point.

This feature request is currently being worked on. You can use this [link](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116253417) to directly communicate with the team that is handling the request.

Comment: The [link](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/116253417) seems to be for Google employees. I do not have a google.com email address. Are you sure that end-users can enter that site and communicate with the team?

Comment: My apologies, I changed it to a public one now.